# Histogram Equalization of matplotlib color tables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and matplotlib and I was wondering whether anyone knew if there were any utilities available to do the equavalent of histogram equalization but to a matplotlib color table? There is a function called matplotlib.colors.Normalize which, if given a image array, will automatically set the bottom and top levels but I want something more intelligent that this. I could always just apply histogram equalization to the data itself but I would rather not touch the data. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own image-specific colormap, but it's not too tricky:

```
import pylab
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy

im = pylab.imread('lena.png').sum(axis=2) # make grayscale
pylab.imshow(im, cmap=pylab.cm.gray)
pylab.title('orig')
imvals = numpy.sort(im.flatten())
lo = imvals[0]
hi = imvals[-1]
steps = (imvals[::len(imvals)/256] - lo) / (hi - lo)
num_steps = float(len(steps))
interps = [(s, idx/num_steps, idx/num_steps) for idx, s in enumerate(steps)]
interps.append((1, 1, 1))
cdict = {'red' : interps,
         'green' : interps,
         'blue' : interps}
histeq_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('HistEq', cdict)
pylab.figure()
pylab.imshow(im, cmap=histeq_cmap)
pylab.title('histeq')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, thouis, for this code snippet. It's very informative. I'll go ahead and try this. I think this would be a great functionality to have included in the matplotlib.colors.Normalize. Perhaps, I'll stop by their forums and see if anyone had thought of including this in a future release. Cheers.

Comment: There's probably an easier way to do this using np.lexsort() and just wrapping the input to imshow, rather than creating a new colormap for each image.  This might be why they've avoided implementing it as part of Normalize.

Comment: I wasn't aware of np.lexsort(). Thanks thouis.

Answer (score 0):

Histogram equalization can be applied by modifying the palette (or LUT) of your image, so it would the definition of a palette that is equalized.

I searched a bit and couldn't find source code for computing an equalized palette, so unless something exitss you would have to code it yourself.

You should be started with the description of the algorithm on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization).

You could also ask for help on the matplotlib lists.