# How to increase the sensitivity of a 2D histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have constructed a histogram reflecting the weights of the cells in matplotlib. As you can see from the histogram below, **the color distinction is so blur that people can barely see it**.
[image]
This may be because of the way I chose to weigh the points.

**How may I increase the "sensitivity"** of the histogram so that it can show the distinctions between the high-weight areas and the low-weight ones?

---

## Edit

Code attached as requested:

```
def generateFreqMap(trajectories, pointWeightLists, representatives):
    # these three lists are all in a one-to-one correpondance
    xOfAllPoints = [point[0] for trajectory in trajectories for point in trajectory]
    yOfAllPoints = [point[1] for trajectory in trajectories for point in trajectory]
    weightsOfAllPoints =[pointWeight for pointWeightList in pointWeightLists for pointWeight in pointWeightList]
    leftBound, rightBound, topBound, bottomBound = min(xOfAllPoints), max(xOfAllPoints), max(yOfAllPoints), min(yOfAllPoints)
    # parameters for histogram
    x_edges = np.linspace(int(mt.floor(leftBound)), int(mt.ceil(rightBound)), int(mt.ceil(rightBound))-int(mt.floor(leftBound))+1)
    y_edges = np.linspace(int(mt.floor(bottomBound)), int(mt.ceil(topBound)), int(mt.ceil(topBound))-int(mt.floor(bottomBound))+1)
    # construct the histogram
    wcounts = np.histogram2d(xOfAllPoints, yOfAllPoints, bins=(x_edges, y_edges), normed=False, weights=weightsOfAllPoints)[0]
    # wcounts is a 2D array, with each element representing the weighted count in a bins
    # show histogram
    extent = x_edges[0], x_edges[-1], y_edges[0], y_edges[-1]
    imshow(np.transpose(wcounts), extent=extent, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.summer) # alpha controls the transparency
    plt.xlabel('x (m)')
    plt.ylabel('y (m)')
    plt.title('Histogram of %i Trajectories'%TRAJECTORY_NUMBER);
    savefig(PROJECT_PATH + '\\data\\%i_histogram.svg'%len(trajectories))
    return wcounts
```

The weight of ith point is 0.995^i. So the weight of the 1st point is biggest, being 1.

Comment: you can pass `cmin` and `cmax` to `plt.hist2d` in order to avoid plotting the bins under `cmin` and above `cmax`, this may allow you to narrow your range of interest...

Comment: @SaulloCastro really newbie here, could you please post it as a complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to generate this figure with some fake data.

Comment: `imshow(np.transpose(wcounts), extent=extent, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.summer, vmin=.95, vmax=1)`  Please read the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Comment: And you posted code, but no one can run it because we don't have code to generate any of the inputs.  It is best if you can reduce your problem to a self-contained example that people can copy-paste and test.  There is also a lot of code here which is un-related to your problem, _how_ you generate your data is un-related to how you display it.

Comment: @tcaswell  yeah, exactly. I realized this when I posted it, but I don't think randomly generated data will produce the similar blur plot as this currently gives me. I believe there are some sort of way to set what color range to display when in a certain weight range. otherwise, if I increase my weight to start from 100 instead of one, the plot will change a lot right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vmin` and `vmax` parameters in `imshow()`.

The problem here is that you have a too wide dynamic range. I bet if you show the color bar beside the histogram, you will see why this happens immediately. Since I cannot replicate your  experiment, I will give some guesses on this.

For example, your highest weight among all the cells goes as high as 500. Meanwhile, your lowest weight is as low as zero. Then your histogram will have to go from its one color extreme to the other reflecting the 500 difference. That is why the distinction is so small.

What I suggest you is that although I do not know your problem, yet I believe when the weight is beyond a certain level, say 50, it is indifferent whether it is 51 or 500. So  with the help of `vmin` and `vmax` parameters:

```
imshow(np.transpose(wcounts), extent=extent, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.summer, vmin=0, **vmax=50**) # alpha controls the transparency
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried histogram equalization?

try [Histogram Equalization of matplotlib color tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858902/histogram-equalization-of-matplotlib-color-tables)

I just ran the above code for a test image in my directory.  It worked well to bring out the details.  I've copied and pasted the code here.

```
import pylab
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy

im = pylab.imread(inputFile).sum(axis=2) # make grayscale
pylab.imshow(im, cmap=pylab.cm.gray)
pylab.title('orig')
imvals = numpy.sort(im.flatten())
lo = imvals[0]
hi = imvals[-1]
steps = (imvals[::len(imvals)/256] - lo) / (hi - lo)
num_steps = float(len(steps))
interps = [(s, idx/num_steps, idx/num_steps) for idx, s in enumerate(steps)]
interps.append((1, 1, 1))
cdict = {'red' : interps,
         'green' : interps,
         'blue' : interps}
histeq_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('HistEq', cdict)
pylab.figure()
pylab.imshow(im, cmap=histeq_cmap)
pylab.title('histeq')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "norm" option for hist2d not exist in 2013, when this question was originally asked. In 2024, I do `plt.hist2d(xs, ys, norm=clr.PowerNorm(gamma=0.1)` to deal with this problem.